# How to replace the version string in a web.config XML file using a Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file where file `web.config` (XML file) is picked up from a specific folder and update (replace) version's value to a new value.

Content of file `web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="abc" value="2"/>
    <add key="Application Name" value="AAAA"/>
    <add key="EntityID" value="2300"/>
    <add key="Version" value="1.38.11"/>
    <add key="AppEnv" value="Dev"/>
</appSettings>
```

The batch file code which I have so far:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "newValue=1.38.50"
type "Web.config"|repl "(<add key=""Version"").*(/>)" "$1!newValue!$2">fileName.xml.new
move /y "fileName.xml.new" "Web.config"
```

Comment: What is `repl`, the command you're using in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using JScript and store it in same directory as the batch file below.

```
@echo off
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" goto :EOF
if not exist "Web.config" goto :EOF

call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "(<add key=\x22Version\x22 value=\x22)[0-9.]*" "$11.38.50" /F "Web.config" /O -
```

The regular expression search string is searching for 0 or more digits or dots after case-sensitive searched string `<add key="Version" value="` which is enclosed in a marking group to be back-referenced with `$1` in replace string to simply keep it and replaces all found digits and dots of version string by new version string `1.38.50`. The double quotes are coded with `\x22` (hexadecimal code value of a double quote) because of `"` has a special meaning for Windows command processor as it determines where a command line argument string begins and where the argument string ends.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a batch file to replace the text and it is working as expected..

But in my modified file it is also removing "!" if there is any commented code. so my complete xml will become INVALID.

My command to read each line and replace the text is

> > Market_New.xml echo(!line:%_search%=%_replace%!

Now, there is 2 ways to resolve it

1) Exclude "!" while replacing

2) Escape character to avoid "!"

but I am not sure how to do it

Please advise.